# See ALL campaigns tagged on an opportunity - not just the one marked as primary

Tags: opportunity, campaign

I have not been able to find a way to show all campaigns that have been tagged to an opportunity except just looking at the opp in Salesforce. Has anyone else been able to do this? Please help!

Comment: Are you talking about the Campaign Influence related list : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_influence_using.htm&language=en_US ?  and what do you mean by `tagged` ?

Comment: The campaign influence report shows only the campaign that was marked primary along with any campaigns associated with a contact on the opp.Sorry, I'm sure of the correct terminology but it would be when you are looking at an opportunity and select 'Add to campaign'. This marks only the opportunity with the campaign. The relationship is one opp can have many campaigns associated with it (not through the contact level) but there can only be one primary. My predicament being that I am unable to query/search/find the other campaigns unless specifically looking at the one opp in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

OK - so yes, this is reporting on data created by the `Add to Campaign` button on the Opportunity's `Campaign Influence` related list

To get the list of Campaigns for a given opportunity, regardless of whether there is a campaign member associated to that Opportunity:

1. Reports tab | New Report | Campaigns folder | Campaigns with Influenced Opportunities
2. Customize as a Summary Report and summarize by Opportunity name

You'll get a list of Opportunities with 1..n campaigns. The Contact Name column will be null if there is no Campaign Member contact tied to that Opportunity. If there are multiple Campaign Members for the same Campaign, you'll see the Campaign name repeated

To resolve those duplicate entries, two approaches

**Approach One**
Export the report to Excel and remove duplicates where the Opportunity Name + Campaign Name are the same across rows

**Approach Two**
Add a filter to the summary SFDC report: `Contact Name equals <null>` - this will show only Campaign + Opportunity

There seem to be some limitations on API access to the related list and junction record (i.e. "there is no access"). See:

- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006n77AAA
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008kdVIAQ